# What to consider when subsampling

Tags: statistics, data, sampling

I have a dataset of 364 people in a control group population and about 450 in one comparison group sample and 150 in another comparison group population. We're doing a full analysis of these data. We've been trying to get longitudinal data for all people in all groups, but that's proving difficult. If we wanted to use a subsample for a longitudinal analysis, would a random sample of each of the three groups be the best thing (using a different sample number for each considering confidence levels)? I feel like there's some kind of statistical consideration that I'm not thinking about. Thanks!